# Updating the JenkinsX preview alias fails the deployment with "ImagePullBackOff" error

Tags: openshift, jenkins-x

JenkinsX is deploying the micro service when a pull request is created with preview as pod alias.

```
- alias: preview
  name: list-manager
  repository: file://../list-manager
```

This pod name is missing the name of the micro service that is being deployed.

```
preview-6bbd6dc88f-pvjjf                     1/1       Running   0          20h
```

I want deploy the service with an updated preview alias as below,

```
- alias: preview-list-manager
  name: list-manager
  repository: file://../list-manager
```

This update fails the deployment with "ImagePullBackOff" error.

```
preview-list-manager-886bc5774-cf88g         0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          44s
```

Error log:

```
  Warning  Failed          1m (x2 over 1m)   kubelet, worker-1.novalocal  Failed to pull image "draft:dev": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = repository docker.io/draft not found: does not exist or no pull access
  Warning  Failed          1m (x2 over 1m)   kubelet, worker-1.novalocal  Error: ErrImagePull
```

Instead of picking up the latest image it is taking draft and dev as image and tag respectively. Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the preview alias in the values.yaml file under preview directory as well to resolve the issue.

```
preview-list-manager:
  image:
    repository:
    tag:
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```